# Activiti: Unable to read a task variable(defined in process definition) in listener

Tags: activiti

In process definition, I have a user task for whihc I have defined a variable as:

```
<userTask id="myTask" name="myTaskName" activiti:actionType="coding"....>
```

I have a listener to read the variable:

> VariableInstance myVariable = taskService.getVariableInstanceLocal(delegateTask.getId(),"actionType");

But it returns null.

I also tried with:

> String actionType = (String)taskService.getVariableLocal(delegateTask.getId(),"actionType");

This too returns null.

How to get actionType in listener?

Comment: i'm not aware of any attribute called `activiti:actionType`. could you please elaborate on your requirement?

Comment: I am trying to have a custom attribute. And based on its value, appropriate handling is done in java code in listener.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using two parameters of `getVariableLocal()` method? Only one parameter is required, namely you custom attribute name.

You shoud use just `task.getVariableLocal("customAttributeName");` to get it's value.

Hope it helps.